# Assertion failure on picker view

Tags: crash, ios6, uipickerview

I'm getting an assertion failure while scrolling a picker view w/ zero data(zero rows). While scrolling the picker view I'm getting this crash. Testing on iOS 6

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableViewRowData.m:1630
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at
>   invalid index path ( 2 indexes [0, 0])'

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: This actually just showed up for me when everyone started updating to iOS6.  I had zero crashes related to this before the iOS release.

Comment: I can confirm this is iOS 6 only. iOS 5 does not crash with an empty picker view.

Comment: Phew. Aha.. I wondered why our app suddenly started crashing all over the place. Thanks above commenters for noticing!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've the same problem

I don't know reason why it is happen,

but it can be fixed in ios6 (how it works in ios5 I didn't check):

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ([self getCount] == 0)
        return 1;
     return [self getCount];
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:   (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
   if ([self getCount] == 0)
       return nil;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks ... weird, I wonder if it's a bug in the framework

Comment: It's gotta be... seems strange to have to return 1 when it's empty

Comment: @iWasRobbed did you get a chance to file a bug report for this ?

Comment: This trick did not solve the crash in my App. My solution is to not present the pickerview when the datasource is empty.

Comment: As making row count always to at least 1, you can have side effects. So alternatively, you can also use picker.userInteractionEnabled=NO or YES in your data update code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually very simple!  After having some trouble with this myself, I discovered that you must set the delegate and the dataSource to the view controller that the picker view is connected to.

Comment: With out delegate and datasource it will never ges into delegate methods of it.