# iOS crash in main.m, how to find error?

Tags: ios, crash, program-entry-point

I am receiving some crash logs for an iOS app for a crash that I can't reproduce and don't have any steps to reproduce it for.

The crash log tells me that the crash originates in main.m, after that it's all system library calls. Can you give me a hint how I can find out where and why the app is crashing?

Here is the complete symbolicated crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 45C9CD85-2F19-4A29-B6E7-AFD43C7DD77F
CrashReporter Key:   [TODO]
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         radar [2327]
Path:            /Users/USER/radar.app/radar
Identifier:      com.example.radar
Version:         1.0
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-01-20 17:55:41 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 6.0.2 (10A551)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x37a5a350
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath 0x1e0c26b0> 2 indexes [0, 0])'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3889b3e7 __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33e51963 _objc_exception_throw + 31
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3889b29d +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   Foundation                          0x312247b3 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 91
4   UIKit                               0x320dc057 -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:] + 243
5   UIKit                               0x320f98d9 -[UITableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:] + 113
6   UIKit                               0x322635eb -[UIPickerTableView contentOffsetForRowAtIndexPath:] + 47
7   UIKit                               0x3243254b -[UIPickerTableView scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:] + 343
8   UIKit                               0x321ce0c3 -[UIScrollView _endPanWithEvent:] + 3699
9   UIKit                               0x321e741d -[UIScrollView handlePan:] + 125
10  UIKit                               0x321c8be9 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 129
11  UIKit                               0x32190361 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 393
12  UIKit                               0x3237cba3 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0543 + 47
13  UIKit                               0x320b4853 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 219
14  UIKit                               0x320b329d _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 1165
15  UIKit                               0x320be1b7 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 767
16  UIKit                               0x320bdd83 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 91
17  UIKit                               0x320ab8b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 381
18  UIKit                               0x320ab1bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6199
19  GraphicsServices                    0x384ec5f7 _PurpleEventCallback + 591
20  GraphicsServices                    0x384ec227 PurpleEventCallback + 35
21  CoreFoundation                      0x388703e7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
22  CoreFoundation                      0x3887038b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 139
23  CoreFoundation                      0x3886f20f __CFRunLoopRun + 1383
24  CoreFoundation                      0x3736023d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
25  CoreFoundation                      0x373600c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
26  GraphicsServices                    0x316aa33b _GSEventRunModal + 75
27  UIKit                               0x3821a291 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
28  radar                               0x00002073 main (main.m:16)
29  radar                               0x00002028 start + 40


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5a350 ___pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3356c36b _abort + 95
2   radar                               0x000279e7 uncaught_exception_handler + 27
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3889b6cf __handleUncaughtException + 627
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x378f4a49 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 129
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x31c9311b _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x31c931b4 std::terminate() + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3637762b ___cxa_rethrow + 95
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x33e519b5 _objc_exception_rethrow + 13
9   CoreFoundation                      0x373602a1 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 457
10  CoreFoundation                      0x373600c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
11  GraphicsServices                    0x316aa33b _GSEventRunModal + 75
12  UIKit                               0x3821a291 _UIApplicationMain + 1121
13  radar                               0x00002073 main (main.m:16)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a4a5d0 _kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x31684378 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 36

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a49e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x388702bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3886f031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3736023d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x373600c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   WebCore                             0x33682a5d _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 445
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b800e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a49e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x388702bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3886f031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3736023d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x373600c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                          0x311b8dd3 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 255
6   Foundation                          0x3125c455 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 81
7   radar                               0x00037fe5 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 81
8   Foundation                          0x31265a41 __NSThread__main__ + 973
9   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b800e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a49e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x388702bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3886f031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3736023d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x373600c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   Foundation                          0x311e209d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309
6   Foundation                          0x31265a41 __NSThread__main__ + 973
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b800e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5a594 ___select + 20
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b800e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5a08c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3350a875 _pthread_cond_timedwait + 45
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x35348dfb __ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexEd + 107
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x3038e537 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 83
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x303a1033 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b800e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5a08c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33514cfd _pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x303216e1 JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 145
3   JavaScriptCore                      0x30321625 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 145
4   JavaScriptCore                      0x303a1033 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b800e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a49e30 _mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                      0x388702bb __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 131
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3886f031 __CFRunLoopRun + 905
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3736023d _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
4   CoreFoundation                      0x373600c9 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
5   WebCore                             0x3371e0a9 _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 145
6   JavaScriptCore                      0x303a1033 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
7   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b800e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5a08c ___psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33514cfd _pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   JavaScriptCore                      0x35348dcd __ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexEd + 61
3   WebCore                             0x3389a251 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::StorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::StorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool ()(WebCore::StorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::StorageTask*), double) + 57
4   WebCore                             0x3389a205 WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 125
5   JavaScriptCore                      0x303a1033 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b800e1 _pthread_start + 309

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5ad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b757f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5ad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b757f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5ad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b757f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5ad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b757f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x37a5ad98 ___workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x31b757f6 _pthread_wqthread + 366

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000     r1: 0x00000000     r2: 0x00000000     r3: 0x3a60c524 
    r4: 0x00000006     r5: 0x3a60cb78     r6: 0x21135690     r7: 0x2fd559dc 
    r8: 0x313023ab     r9: 0x3a608898    r10: 0x3130239c    r11: 0x0000001e 
    ip: 0x00000148     sp: 0x2fd559d0     lr: 0x3352ffb7     pc: 0x37a5a350 
  cpsr: 0x00080010
```

Comment: I guess you will need to symbolicate crash log first, and then this line: 
2   radar                               0x000279e7 uncaught_exception_handler + 27 
will tell you more precise where the problem is.

Comment: your app does not crash in main! it  probably crashes because of  your `UIPickerTableView` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672318/assertion-failure-on-picker-view

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the crash log, it thinks the index path [0,0] (section 0, row 0) is invalid.  It seems to be crashing after a UIPickerView is done scrolling.  Look at your implementation of the pickerview data source and delegate methods to see if anything is hinky there.

Otherwise, you might be able to get a bit more information out of the console log of the device that it crashed on

Comment: The problem is that I can't reproduce the crash and I also don't have a UIPickerView in it. Maybe it's part of some uikit component, will need to dig deeper there

Answer (score 1):

On the back of Dan F's answer. Is there a way in your app to delete a record from a table view? It looks like it's possibly down to deleting a record incorrectly. Or possibly the user doesn't have any data but you're still trying to load it into a table view or something?

Comment: No, the app only contains one UITableView that acts as a menu and contains a static list of sections and rows.